# Editing default.aspx when Site Actions dropdown is hidden

Tags: 2007

I have hidden the Site Actions dropdown for a default.aspx page using CSS.

Is there a way I can edit this page, either by clicking around somewhere in /_layouts/viewlsts.aspx or some other back page *or* by typing in a specific URL?

I notice default.aspx doesn't appear in Shared Documents unlike other Basic Pages can.

Comment: add sharedview=shared&toolpaneview=2 to the URL to view in edit mode. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: default.aspx doesn't exist in a library at all, just the "Root Folder" of the website. You can see how it exists in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I think it can be helpful: you need to execute some javascript to switch to edit mode.

Comment: Please add this as a comment. This is not an answer.

Comment: sorry, how can i do it?

Comment: like you posted the above comment :-) ... add your answer as a coment to his question.

Comment: @Shoban People need at least 50 reputation to post comments, so I've converted his answer to a comment for now.

Comment: ah.. ok.. sorry missed that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've two options:

- Use the following string (just paste it into your Webbrowser address bar) while you have the default.aspx page open:

  javascript:MSOLayout_ToggleLayoutMode();

You can also add this script to your Webbrowser favorites and use it as bookmarklet.

- Append "DisplayMode=Design" to the url, like this:

  http://server/site/default.aspx?DisplayMode=Design