# Any way to open Web Part Properties via a URL?

Tags: web-part, web-part-property

Normally, we add a web part to the page. To edit the properties, we edit the page and click on "Edit Web Parts".

Can we open the Web Part properties page via a query string like we can open the web part in maintenance mode by appending "?Contents=1" at the page URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the page in edit mode by appending ?mode=edit, but you cannot specify which web part to show the tool pane for.

Comment: it does not work :(

Comment: To clarify, Wictor is saying it is not possible to open the Web Part properties pane for a specific web part... only open the page in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

See if the answer posted here helps:

[Editing default.aspx when Site Actions dropdown is hidden](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15593/editing-default-aspx-when-site-actions-dropdown-is-hidden/15651#15651)